# Accessing Hashtable Column in Pivot table in SQl server

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I want my data to be display like this

1 | 2 | 3 | 4 ......
P | p | A | P......

actually i want 31 days Attendance in pivoted way. i wrote this query below

```
SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY EmpId ASC) AS RowNo,
  CourseID INTO #Mytab
FROM tblEnrolment_Learner

select * 
from 
(
    SELECT  CourseID
  FROM #Mytab ap
) src
pivot
(
  COUNT(CourseID)
  for RowNo in ([1],[2])
) piv ;

DROP table #Mytab
```

this was a practice query which was failed and i got this error

> Invalid column name 'RowNo'.

Unable to access hashtable column in Pivot.
where i am wrong ??

Comment: where is your row_no column in `src` .. sub query that would be like  `SELECT RowNo , CourseID
  FROM #Mytab`.

Comment: select * 
from 
(
    SELECT  CourseID
  FROM #Mytab ap
) src

In this part there should be RowNo column too ??

Comment: Yes exactly same as previous comment .

Comment: Owh i got it.
Thanks that work for me!

Answer (score 1):

You are dropping the column prior to use in pivot. Try it like:

```
SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY EmpId ASC) AS RowNo,
  CourseID INTO #Mytab
FROM tblEnrolment_Learner;

SELECT CourseID, [1], [2] FROM #Mytab src
pivot
(
  COUNT(CourseID)
  for RowNo in ([1],[2])
) piv ;

DROP table #Mytab;
```